# Display Ionic App In Web Browser With Specified Styling

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have an Ionic app that I am working on. I have an Android device that I can test it on, but I do not have a way to test my app on iOS. Is it possible to test my app (visually only, not native functionality) for iOS without having a physical iOS device?

---

I have tried work arounds and searched for other solutions, but came up empty.

I tried to get a virtual machine of MacOS, but ran into many problems. Tried for days to fix it, but nothing worked, even the ones that people said worked for their same situation.

Attempted to use Safari to test it, but the only way to get Safari on Windows is downloading an old, out-dated version, since it is no longer supported for Windows. And that version doesn't support arrow functions, and so my app doesn't work, since Angular's styles.js and many other files use them.

---

Is there something in Ionic files that I can specify which styles to apply when displaying on the web?
Is there any another way to do this without getting an iOS device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the purpose is to see the design and navigation of app how it will be here are the below two steps:

First,in modern browsers, if right click on the page, then click inspect.

At this point you can insert `CTRL + SHIFT + M` so it will open dev tools bar at the to top of the browser in-screen, so you can choose the device you need to display like android or ios then refresh the page to make sure all the designs get loaded properly as per the selected device type..

Another way which could be more efficient if you don't wanna go with this approach which is:

in your app.module.ts,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({ 
      mode: 'ios'
     }),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

so in the IonicModule forRoot you specify ios to apply ios design for your whole app.

Now in case you need to test app as native functionality then for sure the solution would not be web approach..
you just in this case to install a vmware then install a macOS version on it, then install xcode and then test your app normally on a simulator and still some things may not function as a real device..

Comment: Thank you for this information! It is mainly for seeing how the styling looks to see if everything looks ok.

Comment: Also, I do want to be able to test the native functionality, and have tried your suggestion with, no success. When I install a virtual machine application, and try to install MacOS, I get a bunch of errors, and I haven't found any solution.

Comment: I don't see what your explaining in the first part. Which browser are you explaining this for, you said "modern browsers" but I'm in Chrome, and I don't see what your explaining...

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now... I forgot to refresh the page